# ModuleNotFoundError: No_module_named

Tags: python, import, modulenotfounderror

I am trying to import some files from a folder. The code is rather simple:

**from** *myproject.resources* **import** *modelselection*

what I got is this

**ModuleNotFoundError**: No module named 'myproject'

offcourse I have the folders called my project, the subfolder resources and within that last folder I have the modelselection file which a function that I need to use.

Obviously I am quite a beginner with Python and I feel is pretty simple error (I Hope) But tricky to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is your current working directory.
Assume the following architecture:

```
| folder
|   |_ my project
|         |_ resources.py
```

You can use `from myproject.resources import *` only if the current working directory is `folder`. You can check the current working directory with `os.getcwd()`.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I ran the code you wrote os.getcwd( ) and my directory is folder as you suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely forgot to add an empty `__init__.py` file in each directory to make them recognised as modules

Comment: Hello, thanks for you comment. Indeed I have the file __init__.py in each directory. What is strange is that if I call another directory it works.